# which phtml file is used view shipping charges details under order items details

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, shipping-address

I just want to know which file gets used to show **shipping charges** details under **order items details**. if its loaded from some helper or other please share details. check the attached screenshot here[image]

Comment: Is it frontend or backend ?

Comment: frontend on checkout page

Answer (score 0):

Probably this file `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\tax\checkout\shipping.phtml`. You may find it inside your theme if overridden. In that case might be `app\design\frontend\PACKAGE\default\template\tax\checkout\shipping.phtml.`

### EDIT

So that you dont have to ask for file names or paths here just go to `admin->system->configuration`. Select your store from `Current Configuration Scope:` and then in the left hand panel go to `Advanced->Developer`. Open the `Debug` section and set `Template Path Hints` to `YES`. Flush the cache and then check frontend. You will see all paths for blocks.

Comment: Try to accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: Don't forget to add your IP to the Client Restrictions so that only you see the template path hints (especially if this is a production site)

Comment: Yes. please.Never forget that. Good point.